# How do I run curl through VS Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, curl

curl is a package that I've been compiling on my Mac [like this](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/025bad1182ff87facbddd280dd07a0fc26b99f45/GIT-INFO):

```bash
autoreconf -fi
./configure --disable-shared --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-mode --without-ssl --prefix="/Users/myusername/curl/install-here"
make
make install
```

which creates a binary file that I can then run like this

```bash
~/curl/install-here/bin/curl --version
```

What do I need to put in launch.json to allow me to set breakpoints in the C code and run curl with different arguments through VS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(On macOS)

1. Install the [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) extension
2. Add a launch.json file with these contents (set `args` to the arguments you want to pass to the curl command):

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/curl",
            "args": ["example.com", "--insecure"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Compile curl (see the [GIT-INFO file](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/GIT-INFO) for details), which will place the resulting executable in src/curl:

```bash
autoreconf -fi
./configure --disable-shared --enable-debug --enable-maintainer-mode --without-ssl
make
```

4. Add a breakpoint somewhere (for example in the [`main()` function](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/curl-7_88_0/src/tool_main.c#L241)) and hit F5 to run the command